# How to setup bidirectional rsync?

Tags: rsync

I tend to run simulations on a cluster that produces files larger than 100MB and I can't sync my computer with the cluster. So I considered setting up `rsync` between the two by following this [link](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-file-mirroring-using-rsync-in-debian-ubuntu).

However, I believe this is just a cron job to sync the backup server with the main server and doesn't work in both directions. What will be the stepwise instructions to set up a **bidirectional rsync** ?

Both the systems run linux

Answer (score 0):

Rsync isn't really the right tool for this job. You can sort of get it to work, using cron jobs and extremely carefully chosen parameters, but there's significant danger of data loss, especially if you want file deletion to propagate.

I'd recommend a tool like Syncthing for bidirectional sync. You want something that maintains an independent database of what's changed and what hasn't, and real-time updates are nice to have too.